# Create spline plot from text

Tags: python

y coordinates system from text to plot a splined text, my first idea was to use opencv to draw the text then get the coordinates from the pixels.

here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# Create a black image
img = np.zeros((600, 800, 3), np.uint8)

# Write some Text

font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SCRIPT_SIMPLEX
fontScale = 1
fontColor = (255, 255, 255)
lineType = 1

text = 'Hello World \n' \
       'I\'m a Robot \n' \
       'my name is "The Terminator 2"'

y0, dy = 30, 30
for i, textLine in enumerate(text.split('\n')):
    y = y0 + i * dy
    cv2.putText(img, textLine, (30, y), font, fontScale, fontColor, lineType)

# Display the image
cv2.imshow("img", img)

# Plot pixels
pixels = np.where(img == 255)
plt.scatter(pixels[1], pixels[0])
plt.show()
```

Right now I have the pixels coordinates, on inverted position, but seems to be unsorted so I can't create a spline with it.

Is there any other way to do this better?

Comment: What kind of output do you expect? As soon as text is blitted as pixels, there is no connection *whatsoever* between them.

Comment: @usr2564301 I want to have a spline that I can use as path for robot simulation in v-rep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try and create the splines from the [glyph outlines of the font](http://doc.robofont.com/OLD_DO_NOT_USE_forums/topic/converting-ttf-splines-to-otf-splines/) much more readily than with OpenCV OCR.

As a one-time job, a graphical editor such as Inkscape would convert text to SVG splines which you can later use programmatically.